# Separable ODE (with partial fraction integration)

Tags: integration

Im stuck half way trying to solve the equation below. I tried using partial fraction integration and I think Im somewhere near. I need to express my answer as stated in the picture as well

Thanks in advance!

[image: Question]

Comment: Hint:  It's a Bernoulli Type.  You can rewrite as $2(y^2)' + y^2 \sin x = \sin x.$  Try a substitution $w=y^2.$

Answer (score 1):

$$2yy'=\sin x(1-y^2)$$
$$\frac{2yy'}{1-y^2}=\sin x$$
$$-\log(1-y^2)=-\cos x+C$$

$$\log(1-y^2)=\cos x+C$$
$$(1-y^2)=e^{\cos x+C}=e^{C}e^{cos x}=Ke^{cos x}$$
$$y^2=1-Ke^{\cos x}
$$

Comment: the method below is much easier and faster..

Answer (score 0):

Use an integrating factor. multiply by $e^{-cos(x)}$. Then the equation becomes $(y^2*e^{-cos(x)})'=(e^{-cos(x)})'$. Which gives $y^2=1+C*e^{cos(x)}$. C is an integration constant so this is the same as your answer. The integrating factor is
just $e^{\int sin(x)dx}$